# How to change style or add CSS in $mdDialog in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I have used the below code for showing a dialog, but I want to change the default style of the dialog.

Here's my code:

```js
$scope.LocationRejectModal = function (msg) {
  var PersonName= msg.from.local;
  var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
    .title('Location')
    .textContent(PersonName+' has Rejected Location sharing Request.')
    .targetEvent(event)
    .ok('Ok')
  $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
      //some code
  }, function() {
      //some code   
    });
  };
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't apply custom style to predefined dialogs such as `Alert` and `Confirm`. If you have to use your custom css rules, you have to implement the `Custom dialogs` or a `Pre-rendered dialog`. In the first way the dialog content will be rendered only if it has to be, for example when you open the dialog itself. In the second way (using the pre-rendered dialog), the dialog's content will be rendered with the page. It will be hidden by default and you show it only when, for example, a button is pressed.

In both of them you can easly apply custom css rules where you need them.

In the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog), you can find more information.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation where I wanted to add custom button styles instead of the default because it was hard to see.

```js
this.$rootScope.isErrorDialogOpen = true;
var confirm = this.$mdDialog.confirm({
  onComplete: function afterShowAnimation() {
    var $dialog = angular.element(document.querySelector('md-dialog'));
    var $actionsSection = $dialog.find('md-dialog-actions');
    var $cancelButton = $actionsSection.children()[0];
    var $confirmButton = $actionsSection.children()[1];
    angular.element($confirmButton).addClass('md-raised md-accent');
    angular.element($cancelButton).addClass('md-raised');
  }
})
  .title('Session Timeout')
  .textContent('Would you like to stay logged into the application?')
  .ok('Yes')
  .cancel('No');
this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(() => {
  // Your code goes here
}, () => {
  // Your code goes here
}
```

Comment: You are genius!

Answer (score 0):

You could also add an attribute to the `md-dialog-actions button` for unique styling as follows

```
    function showConfirmDialogBox(evt) {
       var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm({
           onComplete: function runAfterAnimation() {
                var mdDialogActions = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('md-dialog-actions').children();
                angular.element(mdDialogActions[0]).attr('id', 'customConcelButton'); // for the md-cancel-button
                angular.element(mdDialogActions[1]).attr('id', 'customConfirmButton'); // for the md-confirm-button
           }
    })
    .title('This is the title of dialog')
    .textContent('This is the text content of the dialog')
    .ariaLabel('Attention')
    .targetEvent(evt)
    .ok('Accept')
    .cancel('Reject');
    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
     // code
    }, function() {
    // code
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late but, you can change the template: $mdDialog.confirm()._options.template
Use ng-click="dialog.hide()" for Ok buttond and ng-click="dialog.abort() for cancel.

Example:

```
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()

        confirm._options.template = '<div id="modal-gestion">' +
            '<div id="modal-gestion-title">' +
            '<h3>'+titulo+'</h3>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div id="modal-gestion-body">' +
            '<p>¿Desea eliminar la ubicaión?</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div id="modal-gestion-buttons">' +
            '<md-button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="dialog.hide()" id="modal-gestion-buttonSi">Eliminar</md-button>' +
            '<md-button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="dialog.abort()" id="modal-gestion-buttonNo">Cancelar</md-button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'


        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
              // code            }), function () {

        });   // code
```